# binary check for an operation

Tags: bit-manipulation, bit, bit-shift

Suppose a class has n students due to take an exam.
We intend to devise the quickest way to find out if all students have taken the exam.
Since the state is stored in a repository - read and update operation is expensive.
Is this possible through bit shifting/toggling.
If n=5,the initial state is n bytes of 0 - `00000`
Each student completing the exam pushes 1 ,starting from right.

```
 00001
 00011
 00111

......
```

All bytes composed of 1 indicates closure.
How do we achieve this using bit operations?
Is there a more efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: Why not use a number incremented anytime an exam is passed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have all the steps already:

> n *bits* of 0:

```
status = 0
```

> Each student completing the exam pushes 1 ,starting from right.

```
status = status << 1  # push previous to left
status = status | 1    # set the lowest bit
```

> All bytes composed of 1 indicates closure.

```
allOnes = (1<<num_students) -1
closure = (status == allOnes)
```

> Is there a more efficient way to achieve this?

@Alain's comment is correct: The method you describe is just a less memory efficient way of counting from 1 to n. Why not use a simple counter instead?

```
takers +=1
completed = (takers == num_students)
```

The storage for this will take lg(n) bits instead of n bits.  In either case there will be load/modify/test/store cycle for each taker, so there is no signifcant time savings.  The only reason I could think to use the bitfield is if you are concerned that one person may take the test twice and throw off your count.

Comment: This seemed a better approach in a multi-threaded situation - where counters are always suspect.

Comment: The method you propose is just a different kind of counter with the same issues.   A thread interrupted between read and write may write stale modified data.   However, if your repository has an atomic "setbit" operation, you could solve that problem by setting the (1<<studentId) bit  for each test taker.